# Swift Segmented Control

Tags: swift

I made a segmented control in swift that changes a boolean to either true or false; However, every time I select "selectedSegmentedIndex == 1" in the application, I get error "Thread 1: signal SIGABERT"

My code goes as flows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var translationType: UISegmentedControl!

var state = true

@IBAction func translation(_ sender: Any)
{
    if translationType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
     state = ture
    }
    else if translationType.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
    {
     state = false
    }
}
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't link correctly this line `@IBOutlet weak var translationType: UISegmentedControl!` with the corresponding item in the Storyboard.

Comment: yep, sounds about right, because the code works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

At least using the `sender` parameter and the static type avoids the crash if `translationType` is not connected – which is most likely the case.

```
@IBAction func translation(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
     state = true
    }
    else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
    {
     state = false
    }
}
```

or a bit shorter

```
@IBAction func translation(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
     state = sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var state = true

@IBOutlet weak var translationType: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func translation(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    if translationType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
        state = true
    }
    else if translationType.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
    {
        state = false
    }

    print(state)
    print(translationType.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

Comment: This crashes as well if `translationType` is `nil`

Comment: well if the translationType is nil than uts not properly connected myfriend , reconnect it from the storyboard

Comment: Yes, therefore your code makes no difference at all.

Comment: just trying to help my dear friend

Answer (score 0):

make sure your outlet is connected!  see connection inspector

Comment: This could have been a comment.